# Next Js Accrodion should be collapse when click arrow icon

Tags: reactjs, next.js, accordion

I am using `Accordion` in `next js`. I am following [this (react-accessible-accordion)](https://react-accessible-accordion.springload.co.nz/) package.

Currently it is getting collapse when main `div` is getting clicked. What i want to achieve is According should be collapse when click on arrow icon not on main `div`.

If there is an alternate way of doing this please let me know.

**UPDATE**

Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-using-react-hooks-9uuvc?file=/components/Chevron.js:0-621)

What i want to achieve is [explained here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMY6e.png)
Thanks!

Comment: can you please share your code here? or maybe a codesandbox or stackblitz project replicates your problem

Comment: @OmarDieh I have added the code sandbox link in question

Comment: What i want to achieve is explainied here https://i.imgur.com/b6BVPyp.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first I had to modify the styles so the `icon` is not taking the full width. 
**Accordion.css**

```
.accordion__icon {
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}


.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  /* add flex display and justify content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Add `onClick` to the main `SVG` and pass it through the `props`. 
**Chevron.js**

```
// pass an onClick props to the main SVG
function Chevron(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      className={props.className}
      height={props.height}
      width={props.width}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 320 512"
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      <path
        fill={props.fill}
        d="M285.476 272.971L91.132 467.314c-9.373 9.373-24.569 9.373-33.941 0l-22.667-22.667c-9.357-9.357-9.375-24.522-.04-33.901L188.505 256 34.484 101.255c-9.335-9.379-9.317-24.544.04-33.901l22.667-22.667c9.373-9.373 24.569-9.373 33.941 0L285.475 239.03c9.373 9.372 9.373 24.568.001 33.941z"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

export default Chevron;
```

Finally make the `props.onClick` of the `Chevron` component handle the `onClick` event not its `Button` parent component. 
**Accordion.js**

```
...
// move the onClick from the button to the Chevron component
return (
    <div className="accordion__section">
      <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`}>
        <p className="accordion__title">{props.title}</p>
        <Chevron
          onClick={toggleAccordion}
          className={`${setRotate}`}
          width={10}
          fill={"#777"}
        />
      </button>
...)
```

full sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-accordion-using-react-hooks-forked-l0v8v5?file=/components/Accordion.js:642-963)